# How can I add or delete the front page's blocks?

Tags: blocks

I am using Drupal 7, with the Stability theme. I'm trying to add featured products block to my home page but couldn't. I am able to add them to other pages, though.

How can I add or delete the front page's blocks?

Answer (score 2):

1)First of all create a tpl file "page--front.tpl.php".

2)Suppose you want to place block  in sidebar second region use [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to see the content of your page.

```
<?php dpm($page);
dpm($page['sidebar_second']);?>
```

3) Write following code after executing above code:

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_second']['id_of_your_block']) ?>
```

**for deleting/hide the front page block**

1)Go to edit page at block/region setting/none

Answer (score 0):

You can assign condition `<front>` on each block which you want to display in home page.